# ramda ifElse with props

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have the following object

```
const d = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}
```

What a I want to do is something like this:

```
const type = R.ifElse(R.isEmpty(R.prop('a')), "company", "personal")(d)
```

The equivalent in pure javascript would be

```
const type = d.a ? "personal" : "company"
```

How can I do this with ramda?

Comment: Do you want to check if the property exists, or if it is truthy? (e.g. for `a: 0`, what should be the outcome?)

Comment: I want to check if the prop. exists

Comment: My question is *why*?  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, and a big fan, but unless this is an attempt to learn Ramda, I see no reason not to go with the conditional expression, which is already quite clear.

Comment: It is for learning propose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Disclaimer: I have literally no experience with Ramda.js, I just looked it up and tried out a little bit. There may be a better solution*)

You can use R.always instead of the strings, as it expects functions there. For checking if the object has a property you can use R.has

```
const d = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
}
const x = R.ifElse(R.has('a'), R.always("company"), R.always("personal"))(d)
```

Comment: Very nice, especially for someone with no experience.  I think the original conditional expression is likely the best, but this is probably the best we can get with Ramda.